# What's the Name of the Python Module that Formats arbitrary Text to nicely looking HTML?

Tags: python, formatting, markup

A while ago I came across a Python library that formats regular text to HTML similar to Markdown, reStructuredText and Textile, just that it had no syntax at all.  It detected indentatations, quotes, links and newlines/paragraphs only.

Unfortunately I lost the name of the library and was unable to Google it.  Anyone any ideas?

**Edit:** reStructuredText aka rst == docutils.  That's not what I'm looking for :)

Answer (score 14):

Okay.  I found it now.  It's called [PottyMouth](http://glyphobet.net/pottymouth/).

Answer (score 1):

[Markdown in python](http://www.freewisdom.org/projects/python-markdown/) is a python implementation of the [perl based markdown](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/) utility.

Markown converts various forms of structured text to valid html, and one of the supported forms is just plain ascii. Use is pretty [straight forward](http://www.freewisdom.org/projects/python-markdown/Command_Line).

```
python markdown.py input_file.txt > output_file.html
```

Markdown can be easily [called as a module](http://www.freewisdom.org/projects/python-markdown/Using_as_a_Module) too:

```
import markdown
html = markdown.markdown(your_text_string)
```

Answer (score 0):

[Sphinx](http://sphinx.pocoo.org/) is a documentation generator using reStructuredText. It's quite nice,  although I haven't used it personally.

The website [Hazel Tree](http://sphinx.pocoo.org/), which compiles python text uses Sphinx, and so does the new Python documentation.

Comment: As the co-author of Sphinx I know that one ;)  But it was a lot simpler.  Not more than a simple 4KB library that just convers text into nicer looking HTML.